# Spring Data JPA - Encoding UTF-8 doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I'm doing

```
repository.save(entity)
```

characters like "č","š", ... will be displayed as "?". 
I'm able to display the data right before that line of code and it is formated normally. Also insert through terminal works fine.

Tried many things like :

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
connection.useUnicode=true
connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.sqlScriptEncoding=UTF-8

spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.mvc.formcontent.putfilter.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

and non of them work. I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.0M2 and also Spring Security.

Comment: have u tried, the connection strng without url encoding?

Comment: What displays those characters as "?"?

Comment: Also as per mysql doc, `useUnicode=true` is the correct value and not `useUnicode=yes` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: @Shibashis if you mean datasource.url without both or just one query params, then yes I tried. Also useUnicode=true doesn't work either, but nice catch.

Comment: &amp; Have you tried without the url encoding

Comment: @JBNizet the database, through select

Comment: @Shibashis oh ... you're right. That was a dumb mistake, it was that &amp;. Better think next time when I copy something from SO. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&amp;` should not be added to the connection string. Spring ensures the url is encoded when the actual connection is made.

Also the correct param to be set when the connection is made is `useUnicode=true`